# Part of a sigmoid function?

Tags: functions, terminology

I revised a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)
to use in my research.

The function looks like this.

$$ f(x) = 0.4 \cdot \frac{1}{1 + e^{-5x}}+ 0.3 $$ where $ x \in [-1,1] $.

Is there a specific name to refer to this kind of function?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a special name, but this is a simple transformation. If $S$ is the sigmoid, then your function $f(x)=0.4S(-5x)+0.3$. I would probably describe this as an affine transformation of the sigmoid function since it is $A \circ S$ for some affine function $A$. These sorts of transformations are discussed in "precalculus" classes and equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole class of such functions used in computer science are [**activation functions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function), and to be more descriptive you might say that it is shifted sigmoid function, but I don't know if there's a specific term for this. It is also scaled, but nobody really mentions scaling as it is usually irrelevant. Neither do people really care about the restriction to $[-1,1]$, since if you can use the restricted function, you can also use the unrestricted function.